# automaticaly create csv file using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

for a project where I want to record sensor data with a Raspberry Pi, I want to save the measurement series for each hour as a new csv file.

How is it possible to automatically create a CSV file with python that has the start and end time of the measurement as name?

EDIT: My Df looks like this:
[image: Df]

I would like to Name the csv files as following: "StartDate + EndDate .csv" But i dont know how to get this working...
Here is my approach:

```
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd


dht_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11

dht_11_pin = 4


data = {'Date': [], 'Temperature': []}


def readDht11Values(data):
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(dht_sensor, dht_11_pin)
        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
                date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S')
                #print(date)
                data["Date"].append(date)
                #print('Temperatur={0:0.1f}*C Luftfeuchtigkeit={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))
                data["Temperature"].append(temperature)
                          
                
        else:
                print('DHT11')
        return data

def save_file(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    start = df["Date"][0]
    end = df["Date"][len(df)]
    name = str(start)+str(end)
    filename = str(name)+".csv"
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

for i in range(0,3):
    i = i+1
    data = readDht11Values(data)
    time.sleep(2)


save_file(data)
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what is the error returned by Python ? Also can you give an example of what your dataframe looks like ? Especially the `Date` column. `datetime.strftime()` already returns a string so there should be no need to cast `str()` on start date and end date.

Comment: Is your code working (and thus asking how to ameliorate) or not working (and thus asking how to make it work)?

Comment: Sorry! I added a picture of my df!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a normal `csv` file, one can get away without using pandas at all. For example

```py
def save_file(data):
    filename = f"{data['Date'][0]}to{data['Date'][-1]}.csv"  # list[-1] gives last element in the list
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        for i in range(0, len(data['Date']):
            file.write(f"{data['Date'][i]},{data['Temperature'][i]}\n")
```

Avoiding pandas can be very useful since it is a kind of an overkill for only writing csv files